# Настройка закрытия окна JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на "крестик" окно не закрывалось. Как можно настроить закрытие окна? Ничего не нашел в интернете

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самое простое решение - убрать отображение всех значков.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Ещё вариант обработать событие закрытия окна:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @dhred, добавил в ответ. Можно просто поглощать событие.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)